# Web Service Client Testing

Tags: web-services, soap, integration-testing, regression-testing

There are a number of products for testing SOAP web services (e.g. SOAP UI, H-P UFT, Altova) and plenty of advice on generating clients to use with a service.

We have developed an interface acting as a client to access a web service in order to exchange data with another organization.

Is there a good (reliable, recognized, configurable, stable) way of generating a dummy service to allow the client to be tested as part of an automated integration and regression testing regime.

Testing needs to be extensive, thorough and configurable.

Comment: We believe the way forward is to produce a 'mocking' service which stores the message body in a local database. A second service will be written to allow the automated testing system to interrogate the database and recover both the structure and content of the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any specific programming language you are planning to use? I have recently worked with .NET's WCF framework, which allows for fast and easy creation of SOAP services. Visual Studio even includes its own (pretty simple but useful) tool for sending and receiving messages. And yes, you can test the same service using Soap Ui later on. Another StackOverflow User has already listed some good places to get started: [Check it out!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4274198/3803598)

For Java, you might want to check out [JAX-WS](https://jax-ws.java.net). There are lots of tutorials about it on the web, here is one to get you started: [JAX-WS Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. We are using Java on Linux (Red hat). Your comments have given me some leads which I think have given us a clue to the solution.

Comment: You are welcome! I have just added some more info to the answer about JAX-WS for you to look at!